# Can you view 'my plunks' by tag name?

Tags: plunker

I have been using plunker and like a lot of the features.

- **I thought/assumed it had** a feature to view/search/store 'my plunks' (only your code) by category or tagname.
- **After working on an off with it** - you can save and view 'my plunks' as a whole - but it does not seem to have the feature to filter 'my plunks' by the tag. Viewing by tags - filters plunks by tagname from the whole community.
- **Am I missing something?** Or is this not a feature generally on these types of apps? (noticed jsbin didn't have this when I tried it.) Thought that this would be a powerful feature for me.

-**Tool to best reference my code or code I saved** - If anyone has a workflow that is efficient and would mimic this would be welcome as well. I want to make like a reference 'toolbox' for my code. So when writing a program I can reference saved/tested code.

Ie. Right now - i will link a certain plunker in my notes (ie. google doc) and generally have my own notes in categories which has helped. For DRY like purposes wanted to try and eliminate that step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plunker in production at this date (Feb 2015) does not expose the ability to sort plunks by tag or to search by their contents. This will not be added to the version of Plunker in production.

There is, however, a version of Plunker that is in active development where search and discovery will be first-class citizens. Searching by tag, readme contents, title, included packages (and their versions) will be supported.

Comment: cheers thanks - just checking - do you and if you do - how do you easily reference code that you want to remember. Do you use a different tool?

Comment: I can do arbitrary queries against plunks. ;-)

Comment: I wonder, why these critical features 'search' and 'tag' are still missing